# Node.js: How to save base64 encoded images on server as png/jpg

Tags: node.js, base64

I send from client to server a PNG as a base64 string. I decode it back and save to server. But the file is not readable as a png. Do I have to add specific headers? What am I doing wrong? Here's my code:

```
var base = decodedBase64;
fs.writeFile("/tmp/test.png", base, function(err) {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log("The file was saved!");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
fs.writeFile("/tmp/test.png", base, "binary", function(err) {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log("The file was saved!");
  }
});
```

The default `encoding` is `utf-8`. You don't want to save it as text, you want to safe it as binary data so pass in the `binary` encoding.